# drop duplicated rows and add a count for the repeat count

Tags: pandas

I would like to add a repeat count for the duplicate rows. current example only drop duplicate rows.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A','B','C'],
    ['A','B','C'],
    ['A','D','C'],
    ['A','D','C']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x1','x2','x3'])
print(df)

df1 = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
print(df1)
```

expected output:

```
:   x1 x2 x3
: 0  A  B  C
: 1  A  B  C
: 2  A  D  C
: 3  A  D  C
:   x1 x2 x3 count
: 0  A  B  C 2
: 2  A  D  C 2
```

Comment: Most efficient option: `df.value_counts().reset_index(name='count')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['x1', 'x2', 'x3']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Here, we first group_by x1, x2, and x3, so there will be no duplicates and then count how many duplicates are grouped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas function `duplicated`, then groupby, count and add 1 (to count the first appearance), then some formatting to match your expectations:

```py
data = [
    ['A','B','C'],
    ['A','B','C'],
    ['A','D','C'],
    ['A','D','C']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x1','x2','x3'])
print(df)
df['dup'] = df.duplicated()
df = df[df.dup]
df = (df.drop(columns=['dup']).groupby(['x1', 'x2', 'x3']).value_counts() + 1).reset_index(name='count')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  x1 x2 x3
0  A  B  C
1  A  B  C
2  A  D  C
3  A  D  C
  x1 x2 x3  count
0  A  B  C      2
1  A  D  C      2
```